# I wants to make my UIImage looks same in iPhone and iPad using resizableImageWithCapInsets

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-processing, uiimageview

I'm using this image[image: Image to capInsets]

It works good in iPhone but if i use this image in iPad, it's edges are getting stretched.

I know i can use **resizableImageWithCapInsets**, but it's not working fine for me.

Please suggest what should i do and how **resizableImageWithCapInsets** works.

My current code is this,(but its not working for me)

```
[[self IBimgCellBGImage]setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"img_cellBGView.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(1, 4, 1, 4)]];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cap inset you are using is to small, it just mask a 1 by 4 pixel in rom the corner. Which is transparent so not resizing is being used.

You actual only want to stretch the most center pixel, for you image something like this will do:

```
[[self IBimgCellBGImage]setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"img_cellBGView.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(98, 150, 98, 150)]];
```

You might even want to make the images smaller en stretch it on all device to save space.

Comment: It works but didn't scratched as what i needed(the stretch is too much).
Can you please explain how it works.?

Comment: Well I suggest you read the documentation [- resizableImageWithCapInsets:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/resizableImageWithCapInsets:)

Comment: ok, thanks but can you simplify it.?
And the image stretch is still more how can i reduce that.?

Comment: how did you identifies **98 & 150** values.?

Comment: They are the half of you image size.